# apollo client refetchQueries and onCompleted which one is first?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I am using ReactJS and Apollo

```
"react-apollo": "^2.3.3"
```

I am confused about ordering of operations.

Personally I expected
first `refetchQueries` then
`onCompleted` at the very end.

...but I momentarily saw page that data is not changed
after the redirection in `onCompleted`.

```
        <Mutation
          mutation={SOME_MUTATION}
          refetchQueries={[{ query: SOME_QUERY }]}
          onCompleted={() => {
            history.replace(`someWhere`);
          }}
        >
```

Which is first and how can I match them?

Comment: Does setting `awaitRefetchQueries` prop to `true` ensure that `onCompleted` callback gets called after mutation from `refreshQueries`?

Comment: Both `refetchQueries` and `onCompleted` are triggered on completion of mutation API call by default.